# Error when downloading datasets in tensorflow_dataset: GCS inacssibile

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I have a problem to load data using tfds. When I try to load the data I got the following error.

`ValueError: GCS bucket inaccessible`

To solve the problem I upgraded TensorFlow to version 1.15.0, then I installed tensorflow-datasets using the following code:

```
conda install -c anaconda TensorFlow-datasets
```

But unfortunately, it didn't work out. I use the following code to load data.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
data, info = tfds.load(name='tf_flowers',as_supervised=True, with_info =True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine please see this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PI_P1hXUlVnP5OePaN6zX2MS6eX60kPW) notebook.
I think there is something wrong in your setup try to uninstall `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_datasets` and create a seprate `enviroment` and then install both using `pip install tesnorflow==2.0.0` and `pip install tesnorflow_datasets==2.1.0`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. If I upgrade the Tensorflow to version 2.0.0, can I execute the previous codes that I wrote in 1.13.1 and 1.15.1 versions of Tensorflow in this new version?

Comment: Yes you can and remove import tensorflow.compat.v2 not required in TF 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

GCS Server refuses the connection. Change your country's IP and try again.